# How to 'set link' for an axis to show age from original axis in time format in gnuplot 5?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 5 'set link' to make dual axes.

I've sucessfully linked pounds and kilograms with:

```
set y2tics rotate by -45 right offset 1,0
set link y2 via y*0.45 inverse y/0.45
```

The x axis has a timefmt of `%m/%d/%Y`. I'd like x2 to show the age of the person being plotted, stored in `birthyear`. How do I `set link x2` such that I can map by grabbing the year portion of the time and subtracting `birthyear`? What would be the inverse part (especially as I'm not planning on plotting against x2).

Neither the gnuplot 5 docs nor the 'net seem to have any reward for searching. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Internally gnuplot stores dates as the number of seconds since 1/1/1970. Computing the age [in seconds] as the difference between two dates can therefore be done by simple subtraction. Converting that number to an age in years is much more complicated due to leap years, but if you don't care about total accuracy it might be sufficient to assume that each year as 365.25*24*60*60 seconds.

Assuming you have a data file `test.dat` that looks like

```
1/1/2015        1
4/1/2015        2
7/1/2015        1
10/1/2015       2
1/1/2016        1
4/1/2016        2
7/1/2016        1
10/1/2016       2
1/1/2017        1
4/1/2017        2
7/1/2017        1
10/1/2017       2
```

then the gnuplot code

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
set xtics nomirror
set xlabel "Date"

birthdate="4/1/2000"
birthdate_in_seconds = strptime("%m/%d/%Y",birthdate)
seconds_in_year=365.25*24*60*60.
set link x2 via (x-birthdate_in_seconds)/seconds_in_year inverse (seconds_in_year*x)+birthdate_in_seconds
set x2tics 1
set x2label "Age"

set grid x
plot "test.dat" u 1:2 w lp
```

gives

[image]

Here, age is computed for someone born on 4/1/2000.

Comment: If that isn't precise enough one could use the `tm_*` functions like `tm_year` for these calculations